# How do I make RedisMqServer wait a second before retrying a message?

Tags: servicestack, redismqserver

It appears that RedisMqServer's requestTimeOut constructor argument does not have an impact on the time between message retries. Is there some other way to add a delay between message retries?

Specifically we are looking to add a property to a Message which will indicate how long a MessageQueueHandler should ignore that message if a retry attempt is outstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the `KeepAliveRetryAfterMs` proeprty on your `RedisMqServer` object?

```
myHost = new RedisMqServer(myManager) {
    KeepAliveRetryAfterMs = 10000 // 10 Seconds
};
```

Comment: I am on a slightly out of date version of ServiceStack that doesn't have that property. I'll give it a try when I upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: KeepAliveRetryAfterMs doesn't do the job. It appears to be a delay that happens after the message queue restarts, not after a message fails.